# How to correctly convert a pdf string to pdf on reactjs front end? (blank pdf with puppteer)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, frontend, puppeteer

I use puppeteer to generate a pdf on backend and send it to front end with codes as below:

```
exports.createPdf = async (req, res) => {
    const { resumeContent } = req.body;
    console.log("datadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadatadata", resumeContent);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setContent(resumeContent, { waitUntil: ['domcontentloaded', 'networkidle0'] });
    const resumePdf = await page.pdf(
        // { path: './resume.pdf' }
    );
    await browser.close();
    res.set({ 'Content-Type': 'application/pdf', 'Content-Length': resumePdf.length });
    res.send(resumePdf);
};
```

if I add `{ path: './resume.pdf' }`, puppteer will save the pdf file in back end server, which I have checked and it is exactly what I want.

Now I hope to send it to front end instead of saving it on back end, and my front end codes showed as below:

```
await dispatch({
            type: 'resume/createResumePdf',
            payload: {
                resumeContent
            }
        });
        console.log("this.props.resumePdf", this.props.resumePdf)
        const blob = new Blob([this.props.resumePdf], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = 'resume.pdf';
        link.click();
```

`this.props.resumePdf` is a string like

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
1 0 obj
<</Creator (Chromium)
/Producer (Skia/PDF m90)
/CreationDate (D:20210412022817+00'00')
/ModDate (D:20210412022817+00'00')>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<</ca 1
/BM /Normal>>
endobj
12 0 obj...
```

However, I could only get a blank pdf on front end. Most implements are referred from https://blog.risingstack.com/pdf-from-html-node-js-puppeteer/

Comment: I have your exact problem hahah, thank you for asking it here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Download File from Bytes in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35038884/download-file-from-bytes-in-javascript)
[Downloaded PDF looks empty although it contains some data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981473/downloaded-pdf-looks-empty-although-it-contains-some-data)

Here is the answer, I should encode the pdf string into base64 on backend and then send it to frontend to avoid "byte-shaving".
On frontend, I should convert the base64 string to Uint8 array then feed it to Blob.